# apply a transformation to specific rows and columns of a df based on a second df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have two huge df (especially the first one), which I simplify here.

```
library(tidyverse)
(thewhat <- tibble(sample = 1:10L, y= 1.0, z =2.0))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   sample     y     z
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1    1.    2.
 2      2    1.    2.
 3      3    1.    2.
 4      4    1.    2.
 5      5    1.    2.
 6      6    1.    2.
 7      7    1.    2.
 8      8    1.    2.
 9      9    1.    2.
10     10    1.    2.

(thewhere <- tibble(cond = c("a","a","b","c","a"),
     init_sample= c(1,3,4,5,7), 
     duration = c(1,2,2,1,3), 
     where = c(NA,"y","z","y","z")))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  cond  init_sample duration where
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
1 a              1.       1. <NA> 
2 a              3.       2. y    
3 b              4.       2. z    
4 c              5.       1. y    
5 a              7.       3. z
```

I want to "mutate" some cells of  `thewhat` df to NAs based on information of `thewhere` df. Importantly, `thewhat` is in wide format, and I don't want to transform it to long format (because I have millions of rows).

I want to transform the samples indicated in `thewhere` by the `init_sample` until `duration` of the column indicated by `where`. (And if `where` is NA it means that it applies to all the columns of `thewhat` except `sample`; here `y` and `z`.)

I created a df, `NAs`, which indicates which are the cells that should be NA:

```
# table with the elements that should be replaced by NA
NAs <- filter(thewhere, cond=="a") %>% 
      mutate( sample = map2(init_sample, init_sample + duration - 1,seq)) %>% 
      unnest %>%
      select(where, sample)
```

I tried different approaches, and this is the closest I got. In the next `mutate`, I did the NA transformation for one column, and I could manually add the rest of the relevant columns, but in my real scenario I have 30 columns.

```
# Takes into account the different columns but I need to manually add each relevant column
# and another case for mutate_all when the where is NA:
mutate(thewhat, y = if_else(sample %in% NAs$sample[NAs$where =="y"],  
        NA_real_, y  ))
```

The expected output is the following:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   sample     y     z
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1   NA    NA
 2      2    1.    2.
 3      3   NA     2.
 4      4   NA     2.
 5      5    1.    2.
 6      6    1.    2.
 7      7    1.   NA 
 8      8    1.   NA 
 9      9    1.   NA 
10     10    1.    2.
```

Maybe `mutate_at` or `mutate_if` could work here, but I don't know how. Or some `map` function from `purrr` could save me, but I couldn't manage to make it work for this case.

(Brownie points if the solution remains in the tidyverse, but I could also live with another type of solution).

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: Are you missing data from `NAs`? Like `4z, 5z, 5y`?

Comment: I didn't understand your question  @CPak.

Comment: My attempt with purrr ended with  `map_dfc(select(thewhat,-sample), 
  ~ if_else(thewhat$sample %in% NAs$sample, NA_real_,.x))` which transforms every column, and I couldn't indicate to do something different with each column because `names(.x)` just returns NULL.

Comment: `NAs` should specify which values in `thewhat` should be modified. But based on what I think you want, shouldn't `4z, 5z, and 5y` also be changed to `NA`. This follows from `thewhere[3, ]` & `thewhere[4, ]`...

Comment: Can you update with the expected output

Comment: yes, sorry, I've just updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, we could use `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
lst <- NAs %>% 
         split(.$where)
set_names(names(lst), names(lst)) %>%
     map_df(., ~ thewhat[[.x]] %>%
                 replace(., thewhat$sample %in% lst[[.x]]$sample, NA_real_) ) %>%
     bind_cols(thewhat %>%
                 select(sample), .)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   sample     y     z
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1     1     2
# 2      2     1     2
# 3      3    NA     2
# 4      4    NA     2
# 5      5     1     2
# 6      6     1     2
# 7      7     1    NA
# 8      8     1    NA
# 9      9     1    NA
#10     10     1     2
```

Comment: Almost! It's only missing the case when  the `where` is `NA`, and then both `y` and `x` should be NA in the output. I need to check the` set_names` function, I didn't know about it.